# xs:integer($s) compilation results in "Cannot convert zero-length string to an integer", but $s would contain "4004"

Tags: xquery, saxon

Using Saxon SAXON-HE 9.7.0.15J, and executing this script:

```
let $i := $input//*:i
let $code := substring($i,4,4)
let $n := xs:integer($code)

return $n
```

where $input contains an XML like this:

```
<req>
<i>1234004</i>
</req>
```

I'm getting a compilation error "Cannot convert zero-length string to an integer".

During the execution, the $code would contain "4004", so I would expect it to work in the runtime.

But it fails during **compilation**, so I clearly script something wrong. :/

The same script works fine if I use casting:

```
let $i := $input//*:i
let $code := substring($i,4,4)
let $n := $code castable as xs:integer

return $n
```

or convert it using the number() function

```
let $i := $input//*:i
let $code := substring($i,4,4)
let $n := number($code)

return $n
```

The question then is: why can't I pass a variable into xs:integer()?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hwpif (it is Saxon 10 but I don't think that matters). Can you show a minimal but complete sample where you actually bind the variable to the input you have shown? The error "Cannot convert zero-length string to an integer" suggests your input in that case doesn't have the data you expect.

Comment: There's something happening here that you didn't tell us about because you didn't realise it mattered. Try to put together a complete example that we can run to reproduce the problem. Note also, 9.7 is a very old and unsupported release.

Comment: @MichaelKay The script runs in a system that does the binding. I will try and extract a standalone sample. However, if you say it should work, that already partially answers my question - my expectations were right, and there is probably a bug in the system.

Answer (score 1):

I went into the source code and found that the system validates the user-provided script by compiling it and executing it with all variables bound as empty sequences.

It suppresses XPTY0004 (null value where null is not permitted) but not FORG0001, causing an exception.

A fragile code that needs to be addressed.

Thank you folks!